# How perform native arithmetic in scala instead of method call?

Tags: scala

If I write expression `1+2` in scala, it means that actually `+` method call on object `1`.
But how is `+` function implemented? If it like this:

```
public Int + (one: Int, two: Int) {
    return one + two
}
//Sorry if syntax is not well correct
```

it leads to infinite recursion because `+` is function and calls itself.

So logically, there must be a way to tell scala do "native" addition operation instead of `+` function call.

How to do that?

Comment: Why you need that ? What are you trying to achieve? Also, I would be tempted to imagine that Int.+ method is simply natively implemented

Comment: **First** - What if I want to do alot of mathemtic calculation?, the **second** it is just interesting point aboout scala that I want to know :-)

Comment: @Cherry do you really have infinite recursion (if so, please give us the code) or it's just your guess? It's hard to guide on syntax without actual syntax involved. "native" scala operation is not represented by the scala syntax and it's filled in by the compiler and it's actually a JVM-level instruction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` method is an intrinsic method -- it is translated by the Scala compiler specially. The Scala compiler rewrites `+` method calls to addition instructions in bytecode.

```
1 + 2
```

becomes (in bytecode):

```
iconst_1
iconst_2
iadd
```